# range selector for chart js not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, charts

I am trying to use chart js library and build range selector..
i have iuncluded all library..
but still range selector not showing upo...
can you guys tell me why its not showing up...
proving my fiddle below...
its nopt workimg for this code..

http://jsfiddle.net/TRjGa/11/

```
$("#rangeSelectorContainer").dxRangeSelector({
    //...
    scale: {
        //...
        label: {format: 'shortTime'}
    },
    sliderMarker: {format: 'shortTime'}
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle isn't setup correctly. You have to put the jQuery/JavaScript and the HTML in the appropriate section. I've done that for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya33j/. When I set it up that way, I'm getting what looks like a range selector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the result should look like, but you can't put the JS code inside the html in jsfiddle.

If I put it like this, there is at least smth. showing up =)

```
$("#rangeSelectorContainer").dxRangeSelector({
    //...
    scale: {
        //...
        label: {format: 'shortTime'}
    },
    sliderMarker: {format: 'shortTime'}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v5LTM/